# Azure outbound TCP connection refused

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, azure-webjobs

I'm connecting to non-azure resources via TCP socket connection. I'm looking to do this from a continuous webjob.

When the software is running in the Azure webjob, connections are refused to the remote host. When I run it from a non-azure machine, all works ok.

It seems to be a similar problem to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/732008/outbound-packets-dropping-timeouts-only-with-azure

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm really stumped on this one!

Comment: It's running in a web job, not a virtual machine.

Comment: Are you able to provide example config / connection code?

Comment: It's not so much the connection code as I know it works...because I can run the exact same code on a non azure environment and it works. The problem seems to be something relating to  azure and outbound external TCP traffic. I'm pulling my hair out!